# How to get all synonims from NLTK Wordnet Interface in the way CLI does

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I am trying to obtain synonyms for word `arbitrary` using a following code:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

for i, j in enumerate(wn.synsets('arbitrary')):
    print("Meaning", i, "NLTK ID:", j.name())
    print("Definition:", j.definition())
    print("Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names()))
```

With a following result:

```
Meaning 0 NLTK ID: arbitrary.a.01
Definition: based on or subject to individual discretion or preference or sometimes impulse or caprice
Synonyms: arbitrary
```

However, when I use CLI, I get

```
$ wn arbitrary -synsa                                                                                                                                              

Similarity of adj arbitrary

1 sense of arbitrary                                                    

Sense 1
arbitrary (vs. nonarbitrary)
       => absolute
       => capricious, impulsive, whimsical
       => discretionary, discretional
```

As you can see, CLI shows more synonyms.

I have tried to set WNSEARCHDIR env variable to NLTK corpora directory, so CLI tool uses same dictionary NLTK does.

Comment: The `wn` software in Debian/Ubuntu CLI is not `nltk` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/wn.1WN.html

Comment: Yes, I understand. But how to extract same words with NLTK since it uses same database?